# use jquery1.9.1 and jqueryui1.10.2 at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using jquery1.9.1 and jqueryui 1.10.2 like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// my code here
});
```

I'm using AJAX like this:

```
$('.formu').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './php/calc.php?id=1000',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("hello");
            // jQueryUI component below
            $("#sliderui").slider({
               range: "min",
               min: 1,
               max: data.maxi,
               value: data.valu
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            errorcalculo();
        }
    });
});
```

And I see two times the alert with "hello"... So I search the problem, and may be is becouse there is a conflict between two libraries. 
Then I put this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// my code here
})(jQuery132);
```

Finally modifing tha AJAX like this:

```
jQuery132('.formu').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    jQuery132.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './php/calc.php?id=1000',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("hello");
            // jQueryUI component below
            $("#sliderui").slider({
               range: "min",
               min: 1,
               max: data.maxi,
               value: data.valu
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            errorcalculo();
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm afraid the code doesn't works too...
What I'm doing wrong?

If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: jQueryUI is NOT jQuery; it's a plugin. There's no conflict to resolve. You must be triggering `$('.formu').fadeOut()` twice.

Comment: I think the problem here is the selector `$('.formu')` , how many elements with `class="formu"` are present in the HTML .. Looks like there are 2 of them  .. That is the reason you see alert firing multiple times

Comment: jQuery and jQueryUI are entirely different libraries.

Comment: I have two element with the class .formu @Sushanth.

Comment: Can you check what the second AJAX call is for in the debugger. Check when it's triggered, and what it contains.

Comment: You have two elements with class `formu`? Then there is your problem. It will trigger for both elements.

Comment: That is the reason you are seeing the alerts twice , cause you are assigning the event handlers to a class.. And when you try to fade out the handler runs once each for the element

Comment: Ok, that's it, @Sushanth! but then how I can do the fadein without calling two times the ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest of all is to use a **check condition..**

```
var check = false;
jQuery132('.formu').fadeOut("slow", function(){ 
   if(!check) {
     jQuery132.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './php/calc.php?id=1000',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("hello");
            // jQueryUI component below
            $("#sliderui").slider({
               range: "min",
               min: 1,
               max: data.maxi,
               value: data.valu
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            errorcalculo();
        },
        complete: function() {
           check = true;
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Or Looks like there may be cases when the Slider might not be defined .. So better to use that condition..

```
var $slider = $("#sliderui");
jQuery132('.formu').fadeOut("slow", function(){ 
   if(!$slider.hasClass('ui-slider')) {
      jQuery132.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './php/calc.php?id=1000',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("hello");
            // jQueryUI component below
            $slider .slider({
               range: "min",
               min: 1,
               max: data.maxi,
               value: data.valu
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            errorcalculo();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mZFk/1/)**

Comment: I change it using your way, but I still see two alerts... It has not sense.

Comment: If I put `alert(check)` just below `$('.formu').fadeOut("slow", function(){` I see the first two alerts with false, and then two alerts with hello.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Ok, I understand, but I have to do the same thing without using the slider. And I'm afraid boolean method doesn't work...

Comment: Can you show the code for that case as well where the slider is not being used

Comment: looks like there are errors in your Ajax request .. Remove the complete method and move the `check="true"` to into the success handler

Comment: Same result. I think is becouse I can't set the var within a function. I solve it doing this: http://pastebin.com/3A09uhHH. :) Thanks for all.